# Node module svg2png does not install with -g option (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: node.js, svg, phantomjs

I am unable to install svg2png node module when using -g option. It installs fine without the -g option. I installed phantomJs and made sure that phantomjs is accessible by making a soft link in /usr/bin/phantomjs to the phantomjs installed in another directory. I installed phantomjs itself using

```
  npm install phantomjs-prebuilt
```

Here is the output that I am getting:

```
/usr/bin/svg2png -> /usr/lib/node_modules/svg2png/bin/svg2png-cli.js

 > phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.16 install /usr/lib/node_modules/svg2png/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt
 > node install.js

 PhantomJS not found on PATH
 Download already available at /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2
 Verified checksum of previously downloaded file
 Extracting tar contents (via spawned process)
 Removing /usr/lib/node_modules/svg2png/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
 Copying extracted folder /tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1537780087981/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64 -> /usr/lib/node_modules/svg2png/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom
 Phantom installation failed { Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1537780087981/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/svg2png/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom'
   errno: -13,
   code: 'EACCES',
   syscall: 'link',
   path: '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1537780087981/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64',
   dest: '/usr/lib/node_modules/svg2png/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom' } Error: EACCES: permission denied, link '/tmp/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64.tar.bz2-extract-1537780087981/phantomjs-2.1.1-linux-x86_64' -> '/usr/lib/node_modules/svg2png/node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom'
```

What seems to be the problem?

~
~
~

Comment: have you tried using sudo? it shows the user that is trying to access dir doesn't have access to change it.

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary  Yes I did everything using sudo

Comment: @DhavalChaudhary  The problem is in  "PhantomJS not found on PATH"  There is phantomjs but no PhantomJS. I even tried to create a soft link for PhantomJS to no avail..